# Intellij IDEA: Get notified when a Run Configuration is launched

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I would like to get notified when a Run Configuration is launched in IntelliJ. Basically, I would like to get called whenever the user clicks the run button.

I have discovered the BeforeRunTask class but this does seem to allow me to run any arbitrary code when it is invoked. Is that the right way to go, or is there a better way?

Thanks,
-Caius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Run Configuration dialog, check the Before Launch pane. You can run an external tool or a Maven goal (if it's a Maven project) by clicking the + button. That should give you lots of flexibility.

Comment: Do you know where the entry point is, so I can do this programmatically when my plugin loads?

Comment: I think this is the documentation for it, but I've never done it myself. http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/Run+Configurations